# Unable to call cloud function with service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-iam

I am able to call the cloud function with my login which is owner of account through cloud shell.

```
curl -X POST https://us-central1-<project name>.cloudfunctions.net/hello_work_authentication_required -H "Authorization:
 bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)" -H "Accept: application/json" -d '{}'
```

But when I activate service account and then fire above curl command from cloud shell. I get unauthorized access error.

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Forbidden</h1>
<h2>Your client does not have permission to get URL <code>/hello_work_authentication_required</code> from this server.</h2>
<h2></h2>
</body></html>
```

Service account I am using have owner, cloud function invoker and cloud function developer role assigned to it. I am clueless how this authentication is working.

Comment: I thought I'd have a go at recreating.  I created a new service account and a function.  I tried to invoke the function and, sure enough, a service account with no roles could not call it.  I then added "Cloud Functions Invoker" and found I could still not invoke the function.  Some memory in me then said ... it may take time to propagate .... so I walked away for a while (at least 5 minutes).  When I came back I tried the command that had just failed and NOW it worked.  This leads me to think that "Cloud Functions Invoker" is what is needed AND it takes time to propagate.